# how to remap the keys on a bluetooth gamepad

Tags: android, gamepad, keymaps

I have a Bluetooth gamepad that I want to use with my nexus 7 (2013). It worked great out of the box apart from one snag. The right thumbstickbutton is mapped to back.

Thus makes it really difficult to play games like GTA where the right thumbstick is used extensively.

I tried to use multilanguage keymap redefiner from the play store but it requires you press the key you want to remap but when i do so it goes back out of the menu

I loked for resources related to mkr but wasnt able to find anything not even on the listed creator website.

So i took the plunge and rooted my tablet.

I wanted to use tincore key remapper but found the help and support lacking on the wiki.

Found that the keylayout and keychars were the folders where files pertaining to what physical presses on the gamepad were mapped to (keylayout) and what actions those inputs were mapped too.

I mounted system rw and duplicated the generic.kl file (which I found was the one being used by looking at logcat) and was hoping to use this to modify the behaviour of my gamepad I just can't seem to find how to associate my new layout with the gamepad as the only option that is offered in the menu is still default

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I didn't check enough. Did some digging and found this post

http://gustavepate.github.io/blog/20130714/android-keyboard-layout-logitech-tablet-keyboard/

Seems easy to follow will update with my results

Answer (score 1):

if you're on android 5, you need to make SElinux permissive. google around for an app to do this. without that, it wont apply alternate Keylayout files. also make sure your keylayout file has the correct file permissions (just match permissions of all other .kl files in that folder) needless to say this all needs root.

to associate it with the gamepad, you need to get the unique ID of your gamepad. for example, the file for my Ouya controller i did this with is Vendor_2836_Product_0001.kl

if you can get the vendor and product number for your gamepad, then name the file accordingly, and you've got it. you should be able to get this when connecting your device and checking logcat, but a little google-fu will get you an answer as well.